# When building a new kernel in OpenBSD 5.6, can the name of `config` be something else?

Tags: kernel, compiling, openbsd

I am using the release version of OpenBSD 5.6 and have to apply a patch called 004_kernexec.patch.sig (URL: http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/patches/5.6/common/004_kernexec.patch.sig )

An excerpt of the said patch is as follows:

```
OpenBSD 5.6 errata 4, Oct 20, 2014:
Executable headers with an unaligned address will trigger a kernel panic.
Apply patch using:

    signify -Vep /etc/signify/openbsd-56-base.pub -x 004_kernexec.patch.sig \
        -m - | (cd /usr/src && patch -p0)

Then build and install a new kernel.
```

I'm now at the section titled `5.3.4 - Building the kernel` (URL: http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#Why).

According to it, I need to issue the following command first:

```
cd /usr/src/sys/arch/`machine`/conf
```

followed by

```
config GENERIC
```

Is it compulsory to use the name `GENERIC`? Can I call it something else such as `bsd`?

I remember that towards the end of the installation process of the OS, there was this line that stated `bsd.mp` would replace `bsd.rd` as my machine was a multi-processor system.

Comment: [First search result](http://cromwell-intl.com/linux/openbsd-kernel.html)

Comment: First, download the source from your favourite mirror. (If only the kernel, you need the file called sys.tar.gz). You can read the instructions for this in the FAQ section 5.3.3 http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#BldGetSrc. You said you're currently using release, so you want to read the -stable section not the section about -current.

Once you have the source, take a look at the FAQ section 10.15 about how to apply patches http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq10.html#Patches.

Comment: If you get stuck, email misc@. I don't know why this question was put on hold; as an OpenBSD user it is reasonable that newbies might need help with this and it's perfectly well documented in the OpenBSD faq.

Comment: @user267506: Thanks for the tip on the file `sys.tar.gz`. That really helps to narrow down what file I need to patch against.

Comment: @user267506 Email to what address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenBSD FAQ is your friend in this case.  They have extensive documentation on how to build your own kernel. In particular you want [section 5.3.4](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#BldKernel) but before you do that make sure and read all of [section 5.3](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#Bld) to get a feel for the bigger picture.  I'd also recommend taking a look at Absolute OpenBSD by Michael Lucas.  He's got a pretty good walk through on how to build your own kernel.

Good luck.

Comment: I've read the OpenBSD FAQ before posting for help here. Just to be clear: I'm `not` looking to build a custom kernel. I'm looking to how to use `004_kernexec.patch.sig` to patch my system. And the instructions provided by the patch states that I've to build and install a new kernel after patching.

Comment: @user.stackexchange.253690: Sorry.  You are right.  I've repointed the links to the instructions for GENERIC and modified my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: Could you've a look at my edited post and answer my question as to whether the name `GENERIC` is compulsory? Thanks.

Comment: You can copy the GENERIC configuration into another one and give it a new name but that's something usually associated with preparing and building a custom kernel with different configuration entries (e.g. options and such).  I don't think it really matters though so if you want to use a different name you can do so.  Best to give it a name that distinguishes it from the original but I wouldn't call it 'bsd'.  I believe convention is to use all uppercase when naming these things so you might use something like PATCHED004 to indicate you were working with that particular patch.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't create a configuration file of your own, then it has to be `GENERIC`.  `GENERIC` is the name of the configuration file to use when setting up the kernel compilation.  You can create your own kernel configuration by copying `GENERIC` to something else and then editing it.  The you would put that name in for `GENERIC`.  However, the OpenBSD project doesn't provide support for custom kernel configurations since there are an infinite number of ways you can break things doing so.

Answer (score -1):

OpenBSD's documentation is TERRIBLE. If I change to /usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/conf there is a flat *file* called GENERIC.MP.

The docs verbatim say,

```
cd /sys/arch/$(machine)/compile/GENERIC.MP
```